# Matching dictionary key tuple items in a comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-3.6

When using a comprehension expression that scans a dictionary,
if I know the keys of the dictionary are simple 2 items tuples,
is it possible to "expand" them to named  variables?

e.g. if I have:

```
d = { ('car','blue') : 24,
      ('car',    'red'  ): 5,
      ('plant',     'green'): 12,
      ('box','blue' ): 3
}
```

I know I can do

```
[d[key] for key in d.keys() if key[1]=='blue']
```

and get

```
[24, 3]
```

But this loses a lot of the semantics and I wanted to know if I can somehow do something more like:

```
[count for {(object,color):count} in d if color=='blue']
```

(which I know does not work).
Also I don't understand why the error returned for the last expression is:

`SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`

Comment: `[count for (object, color), count in d.items() if color == 'blue']`?

Comment: `[d[object,color] for object,color in d if color=='blue']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with:

`[count for (object, color), count in d.items() if color == 'blue']`

as the clearest solution.

The error you are getting is because when using the `in` keyword python is trying to assign an item from `d` dictionary to `{(object,color):count}` which is a literal means create a new dictionary. instead, use `(object, color), count` as this is how python expands dict items.

Comment: I'll pay that. ;)

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. 
So 3 mistakes on my side: 1) no need for `{ }`'s around the the variables into which the unpacking happens 2)The key and value part should be separated by a comma and not a colon 3) use `in d.items()` and not `in d`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't quite do that, but you can get close if you "upgrade" your keys to [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). I'm using 'kind' as the name of the first item in the namedtuple because `object` is a built-in type, and although we can safely use it here I think it'd make the code a bit confusing.

```
from collections import namedtuple

d = { ('car', 'blue') : 24,
      ('car', 'red'): 5,
      ('plant', 'green'): 12,
      ('box', 'blue'): 3
}

Thing = namedtuple('Thing', ('kind', 'color'))
d = {Thing(*key): count for key, count in d.items()}
print(d)

lst = [count for key, count in d.items() if key.color == 'blue']
print(lst)
lst = [count for key, count in d.items() if key.kind == 'car']
print(lst)
```

**output**

```
{Thing(kind='car', color='blue'): 24, Thing(kind='car', color='red'): 5, Thing(kind='plant', color='green'): 12, Thing(kind='box', color='blue'): 3}
[24, 3]
[24, 5]
```

---

Actually, you don't really *need* namedtuples, although I think they make it a bit nicer. ;)

```
d = { ('car', 'blue') : 24,
      ('car', 'red'): 5,
      ('plant', 'green'): 12,
      ('box', 'blue'): 3
}

lst = [count for (kind, color), count in d.items() if color == 'blue']
print(lst)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. Try:

```
  [d.get((object,color)) for object,color in d.keys() if color == 'blue']
```

this returns

```
  [24, 3]
```

Comment: no need for `.get` because the keys come from the dictionary itself so it is assured they exist there.